# How do you drag a widget onto a page when editing an app from your phone?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to edit my app maker app using the interface on my phone. Plenty of features work but it appears the drag and drop feature to drag a widget onto a page does not work on my Samsung Galaxy S8+. Anyone else having this problem, or knows how to get the drag and drop feature to work when editing from your phone?

Comment: From my understanding App Maker Dev environment is not designed to work on mobile devices. Those features that do happen to work on your phone are just incidental.

Comment: Feel free to file a feature request for it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833411